# Strange behavior for Or | operator and Not

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-operations

Perhaps it is a very basic question, but it doesn't make any sense to me.

If I do:

```
In: not(False),(not(False))
Out: (True,True)
```

So, the basic logical operation stands that `True Or True` is always `True`.

But if I do:

```
not(False)|(not(False))
Out: False
```

If I use parenthesis for the first condition:

```
In: (not(False))|(not(False))
Out: True
```

And if I use Or instead of |:

```
In: not(False)or(not(False))
Out: True
```

Is it suppose to behave like this?
If so, why?

Comment: `or` and `|` are not the same thing. the latter is a *bitwise or* which is a very different thing.

Comment: Don't use bitwise-or for logic.  `|` has a higher precedence than `not`.  `not` has a higher precedence than `or`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but why is it suppose to give False for this expression?

Comment: `not` is not a function; it's a unary operator with low precedence. `not(False)|(not(False))` is equivalent to `not (False | (not False))`.

Comment: Just as `or` and `|` are different operators that do different things, they also have different order of operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`not` isn't a function; it's a unary operator with lower precedence than `|`.

```
not(False)|(not(False)) 
    == not False | (not False)    drop (...) around literal False
    == not (False | (not False)   add (...) implied by operator precedence
    == not (False | True)         evaluate ``not False``
    == not True                   evaluate ``False | True``
    == False                      evaluate ``not True``
```

But `not` *does* have higher precedence than `or`, which is the operator you should be using.

```
not(False)or(not(False)) == not False or (not False)
                         == (not False) or (not False)
                         == True or True
                         == True
```

The documentation provides a [full list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) of the available operators in order of precedence, from lowest to highest.

Comment: Thank you. I know it seems a very basic question, but I think it is important to be here at StackOverflow. It can be the same doubt of other users.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses the words `and`, `or`, `not` for its boolean operators rather than the symbolic &&, ||, !.